# Swift navigation bar add button

Tags: swift, button, uinavigationcontroller

I need to make a navigation bar button add a string that the user enters to an array without the use of a text field, and without leaving the view controller. What would be the best way of doing this?

[Screenshot of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrZA1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UIAlertController` to create a UIAlertView with a text field in it.

See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller)

You can use the `.addTextField` function to set up this text view.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Value", message: "Please enter new value", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addTextField({t in  //'t' refers to the UITextField
    t.textColor = .red
});
```

Using the closure to set up the text field etc. You can then retrieve this text field by querying `.textFields` (`[UITextField]?`):

```
let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, action: {action in
    let text = alert.textFields?[0].text
}
alert.addAction(ok);
```

For example. You can fill in the rest for the functionality you need such as error checking, adding the value to the database, and refreshing the table view.

You can also add a cancel button with the style `.cancel` when you create a `UIAlertAction`

You then present the view controller by performing:

```
self.present(alert, animated: true);
```